# Skipping the 3-2-1 start countdown in Trackmania Nations Forever when validating a track?

Tags: trackmania-forever

Is there any way to skip the 3-2-1 start countdown in Trackmania Nations Forever when validating a track from the map editor? The track is short and I am testing a tricky jump at the very beginning of the track: I need to restart (using  <kbd>backspace</kbd> ) very frequently and the countdown is a pain (~3 seconds lost for each trial).